# How Can I Describe the Realization of a Passion?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests, adjectives, metaphors

What is the best way to convey a moment of realization/clarity or an epiphany? I am writing a college essay and I want to describe the moment I realized that my passion is math. I am essentially detailing how anxious I was when socializing and presenting to the class. However, at the moment I am describing, I am teaching my classmates how to solve a two-step math equation and my heart isn't racing, my hands are barely trembling, and my voice is calm and unhurried. I then go on to describe how at some time in the future I realize that math and science is my passion in life.

I do not want to say "I discovered my passion was within the world of numbers and science"... I want to describe the feelings and thoughts I felt at the moment I discovered my purpose in life. I want to let the reader see and feel for themselves that what I am describing is my moment of realization. I wouldn't mind describing the moment in a metaphorical way but, again, I do not know how to not be cliche. How can I best do this in the least cliche way possible? Thank you!

EDIT: I want to talk about how the next day I reflected on the relief I felt when I finally did not experience overwhelming anxiety when presenting to my peers. I felt a lightness on my shoulders and I looked forward to math class the next day.

Comment: Before you can express yourself, you probably need to know what you felt (confident? accomplished?).  You have not actually described that, and keep saying you "want to describe the feelings and thoughts I felt."  It is going to be hard to "let the reader see and feel" your moment when you have not set a starting point. After that, others can help you say it. Brainstorm: Write some words down without crossing any out. Add more. Leave the scribbles alone overnight. Edit.

Comment: @YosefBaskin  I want to talk about how the next day I reflected on the relief I felt when I finally did not experience overwhelming anxiety when presenting to my peers. I felt a lightness on my shoulders and I looked forward to math class the next day. Do you think it would be enough to simply describe how I felt afterward? I don't want it to sound too lackluster and it just sound like I am excited about math class. I want to describe it in a way that showcases how profound the moment was for me.

Comment: Now you have started. You felt relief from anxiety, lightness in your shoulders, hopeful. Keep going. Yes, "it would be enough to simply describe how I felt afterward," as long as you understand that the quoted words do not in themselves describe the feelings.